# My css classes in react are afecting diferent pages

Tags: html, css, reactjs, class, jsx

Hello guys so this is my problem , i have one page in react called 'Page1.js' that has one `<div className='container' >`, and this Page1.js imports css style from another file called page1.css with
 `import './page1.css'`.

in this page1.css i make one class called '.container' that has properties like

```
.container {
background-color:blue
```

well so far there is no problem, my div is with it's background blue as it supposed to be.

The problem starts when i make another page like 'page2.js' and i make another div with a class having the same name...

So for example if i make one div `<div className='container' >`  in this new 'page2.js' automatically this div will have it's background blue. But i didn't import the file 'page1.css' on my 'page2.js'.

My questions are:

1. why my page2.js that has no import for my file page1.css is getting the properties for the classes ?
2. Is there anyway for me to be using classes css with the same name on diferent jsx pages and the classes not be overwriting each other ?
3. for to escape from this problem now, for each class that i create i put the name of the page in the class like------------->  `page1-container {background-color:blue}` is that the right thing to do ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because CSS is globally applied when you called import from the previous file.

The import is just a hint for webpack (or maybe some other bundler) to create a separate css file.

To make it private and only available for the file with the `import` you have to use [css.modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) <assuming you're using Create react app>

Try to make an experiment. Rename the file from page1.css -> page1.module.css

and import the style from this file like this:

```
import styles from "./page1.module.css"
```

and apply it:

```
<div className={styles.background}>Test </div>
```

Comment: if you are using  `next.js` you need to call it `page1.module.css` no need to add module if you are using `creat-react-app` boilerplate